# Как в laravel узнать прошёл ли input проверку или нет?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

Произвожу валидацию формы `Validator::make`

Требуется после успешной проверки значения одного поля, отправить на проверку другое поле.
Допустим после проверки `<input name="first">`, при успешной валидации этого поля, нужно будет приступить к проверке `<input name="second">` (Так как данные для валидации second связаны с данными из first)

Как можно реализовать это?

Comment: Laravel валидирует поля одно за другим, после чего выводит ошибки в сессию - "поля такие то не прошли валидацию"(грубо говоря). Пользователь Vadim Voskresensky дал вам правило валидации "bail"( если хоть одно поле не прошло валидацию - следующее не будет проверяться и валидация fail), но Вам это не подходит - тогда можете более подробно объяснить ,что Вы делаете(хотитет сделать)? Цепочку валидаций?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiyУ меня два поля. Первое это ссылка, второе это число. Из первого поля из ссылки я получаю нужное мне значение. Которое использую в валидации второго поля (проверка уникальности записи в БД, первое поле подставляю в where). Я не хочу каждый раз делать запрос в БД для проверки уникальности второго поля, если первое не прошло полностью проверку и как следствие параметр where будет не верен

Comment: Тогда, если я все правильно понял, то "провеверить, есть ли в базе данных такая запись" можно примерно так : 'first' => 'bail|required|exists:name_of_table_here' ; ( поле требуется для заполнения / при ошибке не проверяем следующее/ проверяем на существование в таблице name_of_table_here).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте правило bail к правилам проверки, пример:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

в этом случае, если первое пройдёт проверку, то ларавел отправит на проверку второе поле. (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) Надеюсь смог помочь!)

Comment: Не то имел в виду. Поправил вопрос. Допустим после проверки `<input name="first">`, при успешной валидации этого поля, нужно будет приступить к проверке `<input name="second">`. Так как данные для валидации second связаны с данными из first